# Running SQL script gives syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mariadb, archlinux

I have written an sql script with the following contents :

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS stock_trading;

USE stock_trading;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions(
    user_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    passwrd  BINARY(64) NOT NULL,
    balance_cash BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 100000,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_name,passwrd),
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and every time I try to run it in the SQL command prompt it keeps giving away the error as:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5 in file: 'db_script.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')ENGINE=InnoDB' at line 5

the script appears to be correct but I don't know why it keeps giving this error.

Additional information:
**Operating System** : `Arch Linux`
**Database** : `MariaDB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a stray comma at the end of your table definition:

```
PRIMARY KEY (user_name,passwrd),
                              ^^^ remove this
```

Your full table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions(
    user_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    passwrd  BINARY(64) NOT NULL,
    balance_cash BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 100000,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_name, passwrd)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: sometimes silly mistakes are the hardest to spot but thanks anyway

Comment: gotta wait for a few minutes until one can accept the answer
 don't worry it was the first thing i did it worked for me... @Tim